PC to Android tablet serial USB communication
Like the title states, I am trying to communicate to an Android tablet from a PC. I have a USB-A to USB-C connected between the tablet and PC. The tablet does not pop up as a COM port in the PC's device manager so I  suppose there is another way.
I want to send serial messages to the tablet through a C# .NET WPF application. I have a terminal application on the tablet that will allow me to see any messages coming through via the USB port.
I see there is a SAMSUNG Mobile USB Composite Device controller in the device manager along with a port number. I have tried manually creating a SerialPort in my WPF application with the port name as "COM#" where # is the number I found in device manager, but the port can't be created.
I have also read that people recommend creating a TCP server with the PC as client and the tablet as host and then having the ADB forward messages to the tablet from the PC, but this does not seem viable.
I do not know much about Android development but have worked with ports on Windows for a while. I am thinking there must be an easy way to send the data that I'm just missing.
I am not using Arduino or anything, it's just the PC connected to tablet.

"I have tried manually creating a SerialPort in my WPF application with the port name as "COM#" where # is the number I found in device manager, but the port can't be created." - You cannot create it if it already exists. You need to open it. And that's only possible if nothing else is already using it. You need to post the relevant code you tried. Also mind that "sending messages to the tablet" doesn't really make sense. You need to send data to a specific listener application on that device. And that needs to have the appropriate permissions to access and receive from the port.

So the problem is that I do not have any COM port to open. There's no code written yet because I can not even access the USB connected to the tablet

There should be a COM Port that's an emulated Serial connection for your USB connection. That's how - I am not going to say "most" but - many many many devices work. Including the last Android Tablet I had the "pleasure" to work with.

I see you are familiar with C# .NET development as well as android, problem still exists that I can not find a COM port. I am using Serial USB Terminal application on the tablet, is it possible that this app does not expose a virtual/emulated COM port to the PC?
I have connected some of our in-house devices to the tablet using USB OTG and the app immediately pickup up the device and started receiving messages. it specifically picked up the FTDI chip on the device.

Without Hands-On, that's really hard to troubleshoot ...

Is there a channel I can communicate with you easier?
